# C++ type deduction of variadic template function for n-ary for_each

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am implementing a n-ary for_each with C++ 11 for embedded project. (No later standard is supported)

Anyway, the problem is the failing type deduction of variadic function. Example below somewhat shows my intention;

```
// My implementation attempt

size_t get_len()
{
    return 0;
}

template <typename A, size_t N, typename... Args>
size_t get_len(A (&head)[N], Args... tail)
{
    size_t n_t = get_len(tail...);
    return N < n_t ? N : n_t;
}

template <typename A, size_t N, typename... Args>
size_t get_len(std::array<A, N> &head, Args... tail)
{
    size_t n_t = get_len(tail...);
    return N < n_t ? N : n_t;
}

template <typename A, typename... Args>
size_t get_len(std::vector<A> &head, Args... tail)
{
    size_t n_h = head.size();
    size_t n_t = get_len(tail...);
    return n_h < n_t ? n_h : n_t;
}

template <typename F, typename... Args>
void forEach(F f, Args &...args)
{
    auto length = get_len(args...);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        f(args[i]...);
    }
}


// Example n-ary function

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void print(T arg)
{
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename... Types>
void print(T arg, Types... args)
{
    std::cout << arg << ", ";
    print(args...);
}


// Test - failing

std::vector<int> a = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
std::vector<int> a1 = { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 };

forEach(print, a, a1);
```

However this is failing with following error;

```
/Users/username/Documents/dev/arduino/pure/pure.ino: In function 'void setup()':
/Users/username/Documents/dev/arduino/pure/pure.ino:20:23: error: no matching function for call to 'forEach(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::vector<int>&, std::vector<int>&)'
   forEach(print, a, a1);
                       ^
In file included from /Users/username/Documents/dev/arduino/pure/pure.ino:1:
/Users/username/Documents/dev/arduino/libraries/pure/src/pure.hpp:13:6: note: candidate: 'template<class F, class It_A> void forEach(F, It_A&)'
 void forEach(F f, It_A &iterable)
      ^~~~~~~
/Users/username/Documents/dev/arduino/libraries/pure/src/pure.hpp:13:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/Users/username/Documents/dev/arduino/pure/pure.ino:20:23: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
   forEach(print, a, a1);
                       ^
In file included from /Users/username/Documents/dev/arduino/pure/pure.ino:1:
/Users/username/Documents/dev/arduino/libraries/pure/src/pure.hpp:53:6: note: candidate: 'template<class F, class ... Args> void forEach(F, Args& ...)'
 void forEach(F f, Args &...args)
      ^~~~~~~
/Users/username/Documents/dev/arduino/libraries/pure/src/pure.hpp:53:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/Users/username/Documents/dev/arduino/pure/pure.ino:20:23: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'F'
   forEach(print, a, a1);
                       ^

exit status 1

Compilation error: no matching function for call to 'forEach(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::vector<int>&, std::vector<int>&)'
```

It seems compiler can't deducing the type of function. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: How are you using `forEach`? How is `print` relevant? Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles Sorry, I omit the calling part. Just edit the question.

Comment: there are two overloads of `print`, the compiler has no way of knowing which one you want when you pass it to `forEach`, note that the function doesn't get passed as a name for a template, it gets passed as a specific function pointer for a single instantiation of a single overload

Comment: Sidenote: `get_len` will always return 0.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler says that it doesn't know which `print` function to pass. Note that you have function templates, which are not functions, but templates that need to be instantiated. Does this work for you?

```
forEach(print<int,int>, a, a1);  // <-- note `<int,int>`
```

(edit) Well... the compiler doesn't say that directly, but the `couldn't deduce template parameter 'F'` and `<unresolved overloaded function type>` messages suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to cope is to transform your function template `print` to a NON-template class with an overloaded templated `operator()`.

```
struct print {
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T arg) // etc
    template <typename... Ts>
    void operator()(Ts... args) // etc
};
```

Then

```
forEach(print(), a, a1);
```

should work without any change to `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `std::initializer_list`, if you will use your function with only one type:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename F, typename Arg>
void forEach(F f, std::initializer_list<Arg> args)
{
    f(args);
}

template <typename F, typename Arg, typename... Args>
void forEach(F f, std::initializer_list<Arg> arg, std::initializer_list<Args>... args)
{
    f(arg);
    forEach(f, args...);
}

template <typename T>
void print(std::initializer_list<T> list) // The main version of function is written using std::initializer_lost
{
    for (const T& t : list)
    {
        std::cout << t << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

template <typename T, typename... Types>
void printVariadic(T arg, Types... args) // You still can use variadic version, but only with same type
{
    print(std::initializer_list<T>{ arg, args... });
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printVariadic("Hello", "world");
    
    std::initializer_list<int> a = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::initializer_list<int> a1 = { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 };
    forEach(print<int>, a, a1);
}
```

Edit: as Nelfeal mentioned in the comment below, you can use `std::array` instead of `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Please don't use `std::initializer_list` when [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a perfectly good choice.